# Bukkit prefix and suffix

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How do I make a prefix and suffix plugin? For example, if I do `/promote player mod` the word `[mod]` will show in red color before their name. And if I do `/promote player admin` the word `[admin]` will show up before their name the codes I wrote so far doesn't work
or it will change the whole chat color and mess things up.

By the way this is craftbukkit!

Comment: Do you really need to create your own plugin or can you use an already created resource? PEX allows you to do this, and you can hook into PEX via its public API in your outside plugins to access its data. Other plugins do this too: GroupManager, zPerms, etc.

Comment: You can create the commands and then do something like this: 'Player.setDisplayName("\2474[Mod] " + Player.getName();"

Answer (score 0):

Just get the player object and do the following:

```
playerobject.setDisplayName("<prefix>" + playerobject.getName() + "<suffix>");
```

Comment: This only changes their name IN CHAT!  This will not change their nameplate or their name on tab.

Comment: What is he wanting then?

Comment: He doesn't specify, but given that he wants this for a rank system I would guess he wants to it to change the nameplates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VaultAPIs Chat part for setting the prefix and suffix of the players. https://github.com/MilkBowl/VaultAPI

Answer (score 0):

The bukkit api has a method [`Player.setDisplayName()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#setDisplayName(java.lang.String)) which will change their name in CHAT ONLY.

Bukkit does **not** natively support completely changing the users name.

If you are trying to change the nameplate above their head you have three options:

1. You can add prefixes and suffixes to the name using the [Bukkit Scoreboard API](https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-scoreboards-teams-with-the-bukkit-api.139655/) .  But you can only add prefixes and suffixes **not** completely change their name, .
2. Edit the packets ([Tutorial](https://bukkit.org/threads/info-packets-nms-explained.177955/)), either manually or using something like [ProtocolLib](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/protocollib/).
3. Use a API such as the [Tag API](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/tag/).  (However, unfortunately, it seems this project seems to be inactive, we'll see if someone else picks it up)